# Facebook Like Button Not Appearing

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

http://www.flippish.com/boy-bawal/2012/07/25/

Suddenly the facebook like widget does not work on my wordpress site. I've tried placing the link on fb linter but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the page.  There is something going on with your layout.  Try using the iframe version of the like button.